# geographic distance and mahalanobis distance

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, modeling, distance, geostatistics

I am trying to match individuals based on monthly consumption and geographic consumption in a dense metro area.  Essentially I want to create treatment and control pairs with the having both geo location and consumption (total consumption and consumption pattern) as close to the treatment as possible.  At first I was just creating a radius of half a mile around each treatment unit and selecting a control that had the closest consumption for winter and summer months—I used a Euclidian distance measure between the treatment and control winter and summer consumption variables.

However, this approach doesn’t account for correlation among the variables, so I wanted to measure the mahalanobis distance by first computing the PCA scores for these variables and then finding the Euclidian distance.  This got me thinking.  Instead of looking at individuals within a particular radius, I could use the standardized longitude and latitudes in the distance calculation.  I would still put some kind of constraint on how far away the potential controls can be (I wouldn’t want to compare units form a upper class neighborhood to a ghetto), but the distance metric would include a “closeness” component this time around.  Then I thought I could look at each month instead of total winter and summer to better capture total usage as well as consumption patterns.

When I did this I found in both the PC1 and PC2 large loadings on the WE-coordinate.  Also, I found loadings near zero for winter months and positive for summer months on the first PC and negative loadings on winter months and positive loadings on summer months on the second.  I thought this was kind of an interesting pattern.  When plotted the monthly consumption of the control and treatment pairs the patterns looked similar, so it seems to have worked.  I am just not sure the coordinates have real meaning in this sense.  It might be worth estimating the PCA’s on the set of all possible controls instead of in smaller subsets if I am going to used them, but I think some areas are just too different.
I am just not sure if there is much sense in including the coordinates.  That is, is it incorrect to use longitude and latitude variables in a principal component analysis?  I am thinking they should orthogonal variables naturally so the correlation might be misleading.  I got similar results using the radius method, but I would like to stick to one method and run with it.

Comment: To answer the question about whether geographic coordinates can or should be orthogonal just imagine the coordinates as a scatter plot, and what patterns would need to necessary in the point cloud for the two variables to be uncorrelated. A different approach to this problem is to estimate propensity score models, and include the geographic coordinates in the regression allowing for non-linearities. See [Ridgeway and McDonald (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2009.0034) for an example. [PDF here](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reprints/2009/RAND_RP1394.pdf).